# Succinct API design for supporting both Push and Pull-style Stream operations

Tags: object-oriented-design, api-design, interfaces

I have a C# `interface` that represents an image-file (photo, logo, etc) that's been loaded into memory.

I have different implementations (using `System.Drawing`, ImageMagick.NET, test stubs, etc) - a problem is that these different implementations have different preferred ways of serializing the image to a `Stream` to be saved on-disk or uploaded to a storage service:

- Some have a "pull"-style method, where the implementation provides a `Stream` object that you can read-from to get the serialized data.
- Others have a "push"-style method, where the implementation accepts a `Stream` object and it then writes the data to that stream.

#### Pull-style:

This style is seen on image/graphics libraries that have already serialized or re-encoded the image data in-memory first - or internally operate on a `Byte[]`, and return a read-only `MemoryStream` wrapper around that buffer.

```
class LoadedImage
{
    Stream GetStream();
}

// Usage:
using( FileStream fs = new FileStream( ... ) )
using( Stream imageStream = image.GetStream() )
{
    await imageStream.CopyToAsync( fs ).ConfigureAwait(false);
}
```

#### Push-style:

This style is used by `System.Drawing` and it tends to be used because it performs the image file encoding as it writes to the provided stream which minimizes in-memory data:

```
class LoadedImage
{
    Task SaveAsync( Stream stream );
}

// Usage:
using( FileStream fs = new FileStream( ... ) )
{
    await image.SaveAsync( fs ).ConfigureAwait(false);
}
```

#### The interface: Approach 1: Explicit implementation and an indicator property

I was thinking of supporting both styles through a single interface by having both methods and a flag property to indicate the preferred (or supported) method:

```
interface ILoadedImage
{
    Boolean IsGetStreamPreferred { get; }

    Stream GetStream();

    Task SaveAsync( Stream stream );
}

class PullLoadedImage : ILoadedImage
{
    public Boolean IsGetStreamPreferred => true;

    public Stream GetStream()
    {
        // ...
    }

    Task ILoadedImage.SaveAsync( Stream _ )
    {
        throw new NotSupportedException( "..." );
    }
}

class PushLoadedImage : ILoadedImage
{
    public Boolean IsGetStreamPreferred => false;

    Stream ILoadedImage.Stream GetStream()
    {
        throw new NotSupportedException( "..." );
    }

    public async Task SaveAsync( Stream stream )
    {
        // ...
    }
}
```

But this doesn't seem particularly clean to me - and I believe that if an object class cannot or does not support *all* members of a given `interface` then it has no business implementing the interface in the first place - and instead a more restrictive interface should be used.

(Note that from .NET Framework 1.0 until 4.5 there weren't any `IReadOnly...<T>` collection interfaces - so collections that were immutable or partly-immutable had to implement the interface but throw `NotSupportedException` - though often the interface would have a `Boolean IsReadOnly { get; }` property to allow consumers to avoid an unexpected exception - but it's imperfect (consider a `T[]` array - it's not truly read-only because elements can be replaced, but it cannot be resized).

#### The interface: Approach 2 - Default interface implementation:

I know that C# 8.0 with its Default Interface Implementation feature would allow for my `ILoadedImage` interface to use an adapter by default - however I'm targeting the .NET Framework 4.7.2 still, so that isn't an option available to me. But if I could use it - then it would look like this:

```
interface ILoadedImage
{
    // No need for `IsGetStreamPreferred` property - but I might include it to allow consumers which can use both styles to choose the most performant method.

    public Stream GetStream()
    {
        MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
        await this.SaveAsync( ms ).ConfigureAwait(false);
        ms.Seek( 0, SeekOrigin.Begin );
        return ms;
    }

    public async Task SaveAsync( Stream stream )
    {
        using( Stream source = this.GetStream() )
        {
            await source.CopyToAsync( stream ).ConfigureAwait(false);
        }
    }
}
```

(But C# default-interface-methods don't have a way to require a class to override *at least* one of those methods - because if they didn't there'd be infinite recursion between the two methods).

(I know there is a way to implement the `GetStream()` method using a custom awaitable `Stream` subclass that only buffers a single buffer after each `WriteAsync` call - rather than buffering the entire output in a `MemoryStream` - but this is only for illustrative purposes).

#### The interface: Approach 3 - Discriminated union:

This approach uses a discriminated-union type. A good example for C# is `OneOf<T>` available here: https://github.com/mcintyre321/OneOf

```
interface ILoadedImage
{
    // Returns either a `Stream` or a `Func<Stream,Task>` (i.e. an async method).
    OneOf< Stream, Func<Stream,Task> > Save();
}

// Usage:

await loadedImage.Save().Match(
    async stream =>
    {
        using( stream )
        using( FileStream fs = new FileStream( ... ) )
        {
            await stream.CopyToAsync( fs ).ConfigureAwait(false);
        }
    },
    async func =>
    {
        using( FileStream fs = new FileStream( ... ) )
        {
            await func( fs ).ConfigureAwait(false);
        }
    }
);
```

...but this is **not** easy-to-use - and is downright scary-looking to C# users not used to working with async lambdas in discriminated-union match expressions.

Is there a better way to design this?

Comment: It seems to me that the fact whether concrete implementation uses pull or push-based approach is an implementation detail that should be abstracted away by an interface, not something that is exposed for the outside world.

Comment: @BohdanStupak Right - that's what I'm trying to do - the problem is that, as far as I can tell, it's very difficult to describe that abstraction. The only _general solution_ is to use an intermediate `MemoryStream` - but that is very inefficient because then serialized image data exists in memory in duplicate or even triplicate depending on how the underlying image data is originally intended to be serialized.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe use the alternative TryPick syntax for OneOf? It's more "csharpey"

```
var saveResult = await loadedImage.Save();
if (saveResult.TryPickT0(out Stream stream, out Func<Stream,Task> func))
{
    using( stream )
    using( FileStream fs = new FileStream( ... ) )
    {
        await stream.CopyToAsync( fs ).ConfigureAwait(false);
    }
}else{
    using( FileStream fs = new FileStream( ... ) )
    {
        await func( fs ).ConfigureAwait(false);
    }
}
```